# How do I make an app use a module outside of its own folder, by linking to it (instead of copying)?

Tags: android, android-studio, module, duplicates, directory

This is a very short question:

I've made a module that exist in one folder, and I'd like an app I've made use it, without the need to really copy its content.

In short I do not want duplicate folders of the module.

Is there a way in Android-Studio to make an app's project link to a module, so that changes in the module's code will immediately be reflected for the app's project ?

Comment: I guess installing to local maven repository is not an option? Changes in library won't affect project immediately, but at least you won't need to copy the code around

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle dependecies: compile project by relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975745/gradle-dependecies-compile-project-by-relative-path)

Comment: @njzk2 I've actually asked this about Android-Studio and not gradle, but this should also work. I'd still like to know if it's possible via the UI too. Drag&drop of the path could be really nice as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can!

Inside your `settings.gradle` add:

```
include ':myModule'

project(':myModule').projectDir = new File('../../MyOtherProject/modules/myModule')
```

Comment: In which parts of the build.gradle file?

Comment: Is it also possible in the Android-Studio UI ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the Android team is still working on many features for Android Studio, including having a sofisticated UI for gradle...and also stuff like javadoc support for aar dependencies (which is a bit embarrassing, but whatevs...)

Comment: ok, thank you. I've posted a request about it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175013