# Including Java library built with Gradle throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

I am writing a Java library and I would like to build the library with Gradle and then test it from a local test project.

I would prefer using Gradle 3.3 for my objective.
The library should be built for Java5 and higher.

So far my `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'jvm-component'
  id 'java-lang'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

model {
  components {
    main(JvmLibrarySpec) {
      sources {
        java {
          dependencies {
            module 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
            module 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
            module 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
          }
        }
      }

      api {
        exports 'io.simplepush'
      }

      targetPlatform 'java5'
    }
  }
}
```

The source code of the library is located in `src/main/java/io/simplepush/Notification.java` and depends on the dependencies stated in the `build.gradle` file.

Building the library with `./gradlew build` works fine and generates `build/jars/main/jar/main.jar`.

However when I run a test project from IntelliJ (after including `main.jar` into the test project), I get the following runtime error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity`.

It seems like the test project does not know about the runtime dependencies needed by my library.

I am not sure on what is the correct way to tell the test project about the dependencies of my library.
I do not want a fat jar which includes all dependencies.
Listing all dependencies in the test project itself is also not an option.
Preferably I want the library itself to tell the test project about which dependencies it needs.

Comment: Why not add library tests to the library itself?

Comment: Because I want to learn about the process of including a library into a project with Gradle.

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer to this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975745/gradle-dependencies-compile-project-by-relative-path

Comment: Why using Gradle then? when you want to publish to mavenLocal repo ? Gradle has it own cached artifact directory. Is the project using the artifact Maven ? As well you said you want an executable jar? in this case you need to pack needed dependencies within the jar.

Comment: @Krystian_K I want to use Gradle because I have to anyway when I want to publish the library on Maven Central.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by changing several things.
Thanks to [@Babl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874814/babl) for pointing me in the right direction.
My new library `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'maven-publish'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
  compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
}

publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      groupId 'io.simplepush'
      artifactId 'project1-sample'
      version '1.1'

      from components.java
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can push the library to the local maven repository with `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`.

The `build.gradle` of the test project uses the `application` plugin and defines a main class (which is `Hello` in my case). Then I can run `./gradlew installDist` to generate an executable file (see [Application plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)) which puts all dependencies in the classpath and runs just fine.

```
group 'com.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'io.simplepush:project1-sample:1.1'
}

mainClassName = "Hello"
```

Answer (score 6):

The library jar which you have created does not contain any dependency information which the IDE/Gradle can then resolve to be able to compile/run the test project. I see that you are using the maven central repository so what you need to do is to publish your library to your local maven repository and in the test project just add a dependency information (no just plain jar file).

So in both library and test project `build.gradle` add a maven local repository config.

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}
```

And now you need to publish the library to local repository. As you are using the gradle 3.3 you can use the [Maven Publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

So in the library `build.gradle` add a maven publishing information.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'io.simplepush'
            artifactId 'project1-sample'
            version '1.1'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle “maven-publish” plugin makes this easy to publish to local repository automatically creating a PublishToMavenLocal task.
So you can just run

> gradle publishToMavenLocal

Which will publish your library with all the dependency information into local maven repository.

And then you just need to add a library information to you test projects `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
        // other dependencies .....
        module 'io.simplepush:project1-sample:1.1'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the direction I want to take. After some further modification (removing the whole model section, specifying the dependencies with `compile` on the first level of the `build.gradle` file and loading the java plugin) it seems to generate a local maven library which correctly specifies its dependencies in its pom file. However I still get the same error. Could you maybe elaborate on how to correctly generate an executable jar with gradle for the test project?

Answer (score 0):

This specify what repositories to check to fetch the dependencies from

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Therefore, anything that is in the `dependecies{}` will be fetched from those above.

If the test project is not coupled with the library project, (@RaGe example) new test project needs to know where to take the dependency from - you need to publish it, using preferred method.

After that, your new test project needs to specify the library with the preferred configuration (compile...runtime etc) in the build.gradle `dependencies{}`

After that depending on IDE you need to refresh the classpath and download the dependency from the specified before repository, the transitive dependencies specified in the library dependency (in this case) will get fetched from test projects `repositories{}`

---

Library build.gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  module 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  module 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
  module 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
}
```

---

test project build.gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() repository to fetch transitives
  mavenLocal() or any other repo that you published the library to
}

dependencies {
  pref-conf librarygroup:name:version
}
```

You can use idea or eclipse plugin in gradle for `gradle idea` or `gradle eclipseClasspath` tasks to refresh it with your freshly added dependencies.

With this solution, you should not need to pack the transitive dependencies within the library,

PS. I am just confused after you said you want executable jar.