# Gradle cannot find project (project with path $ cannot be found)

Tags: gradle, libgdx

This project (example) depends on a project defined in the parent directory. It is not part of the parent directory project's build at all. However, Gradle never finds a project in any of my folders with projects in them. The parent directory contains a multiplatform multiproject library project for libGDX. I cannot call project() and find one in ANY directory so far...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Settings file '/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/settings.gradle' line: 2

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating settings 'example'.
    > Project with path '/../html' could not be found.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    CONFIGURE FAILED

    Total time: 0.124 secs
```

gdx-complextext/example/settings.gradle

```
include 'desktop', 'android', 'ios', 'html', 'core', 'ios-moe'
includeBuild(project("/../html"))
```

gdx-complextext/build.gradle

```
ext {
    GROUPID = 'com.athenaeumapps.gdxcomplextext'
    VERSION = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        maven { url uri(System.getenv("INTEL_MULTI_OS_ENGINE_HOME") + "/gradle") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.goharsha:gwt-opentype:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.2.0'
        classpath group: 'org.multi-os-engine', name: 'moe-gradle', version: '1.1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    ext {
        appName = 'gdx-complextext'
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.2.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }

    group = GROUPID
    version = VERSION
}

project(":android") {
    configurations {
        custom
        compile.extendsFrom custom
    }

    eclipse {
        project {
            name = appName + "-android"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"

    }
}


project(":core") {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    apply from: '../publish.gradle'

    configurations {
        custom
        compile.extendsFrom custom
    }

    eclipse {
        project {
            name = appName + "-core"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}




project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    apply from: '../publish.gradle'

    configurations {
        custom
        compile.extendsFrom custom
    }

    eclipse {
        project {
            name = appName + "-desktop"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}


project(":html") {
    apply plugin: 'java'


    apply from: '../publish.gradle'

    configurations {
        custom
        compile.extendsFrom custom
    }

    eclipse {
        project {
            name = appName + "-html"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}



project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'robovm'

    apply from: '../publish.gradle'

    configurations {
        custom
        compile.extendsFrom custom
    }

    eclipse {
        project {
            name = appName + "-ios"
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        compile project(':core')

        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"

    }
}


project(":ios-moe") {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'moe'


    apply from: '../publish.gradle'

    configurations {
        custom
        compile.extendsFrom custom
        natives
    }

    eclipse {
        project {
            name = appName + "-ios-moe"
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        compile project(':core')

        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-moe:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Upon trying just includeBuild, I get this:

includeBuild("${rootProject.projectDir}/../html")

Comment: Might be silly but have you tried ending with a `/`: `../html/`?

Comment: Not silly at all.. but it has been tried to no avail.

Comment: Please be more careful with tags - this question isn't about project management.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use another way to obtain a project location using `rootProject.projectDir` then add `../html`, also according to [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) there's no need to wrap into `project` e.g. use only `includeBuild` like below:

```
includeBuild("${rootProject.projectDir}/../html")
```

Another example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975745/gradle-dependencies-compile-project-by-relative-path)

Comment: Settings file '/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/settings.gradle' line: 2
Could not compile settings file '/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/settings.gradle'.
startup failed:
settings file '/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/settings.gradle': 2: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 2, column 46.
   {rootProject.projectDir}/../')

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: Settings file '/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/settings.gradle' line: 2
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'example'.
Could not find method includeBuild() for arguments [/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/../html] on settings 'example' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

Comment: 2.14.1.... which I just realized came soon after includeBuild was added

Comment: Please take a look at provided link to the answer, it looks similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I read that article before even coming here and checked it again. I am using your answer code exactly, and no project is found...

Comment: includeBuild("${rootProject.projectDir}/../html")

Settings file '/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/settings.gradle' line: 2
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'example'.
Could not find method includeBuild() for arguments [/home/athenacadence/git/gdx-complextext/example/../html] on settings 'example' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip'.
 at